# How do I tell how many GB a RAM stick has?

Tags: memory, ddr3

My old laptop broke down and now I've stripped it down to the motherboard.

I've collected all the useful items, such as the RAM sticks.

I now have got 2 sticks, one 4 GB and one 8 GB. How do I tell which is which? I want to place the 8 GB stick into my laptop.

Comment: Picking RAM from a broken computer: I'd recommend running `memtest86`on the computer you put these into - it will also tell you how much of the memory it detects (may differ from actual size => broken!)

Answer (score 4):

Unless the RAM sticks keep the manufacturer label with the reference (e.g. Kingston usually uses a long reference KVR***** that includes '2G' or '8G' in it), your easiest way is to test each stick and check using your OS utilities.
[image]

Comment: The writing on old RAM is sometimes faded. As an alternative approach, you could Google the part number of the individual memory banks, find out their size and multiply the size times the number of banks.